# Making a javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to ask if I could combine the following JavaScript code into one file?

as I enter in one file.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(&#39;#slider-with-blocks-1&#39;).royalSlider({arrowsNav:true,arrowsNavAutoHide:false,fadeinLoadedSlide:false,controlNavigationSpacing:0,controlNavigation:&#39;bullets&#39;,imageScaleMode:&#39;none&#39;,imageAlignCenter:false,blockLoop:true,loop:true,numImagesToPreload:6,transitionType:&#39;fade&#39;,keyboardNavEnabled:true,block:{delay:400} })  });
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(&#39;.credit &#39;).append(&#39; credit by &lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&#39;);
$(&#39;.credit span&#39;)
.html($(&#39;<a/>&#39;).attr(&#39;href&#39;,&#39;www.google.com&#39;)
 .text(&#39;This is my link to google!&#39;)
 );
$(&#39;.credit span a&#39;)
.attr(&#39;id&#39;, &#39;credit&#39;);
});
```

and

```
$(&quot;[role=&#39;navigation&#39;]&quot;).flexNav();
```

and

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (!document.getElementById('credit') || document.getElementById('credit').href != "http://www.google.com/") {
        alert('Kreditnya jangan diilangin sob!');
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried stuffing the code into one file?

Comment: Please please please unescape your quotes!

Comment: @Blender Yes, I want to make in a single file.

Comment: @SodiycKurniawan: But have you tried doing it? Just stick all of those chunks of code into one file. It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store this in a js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider-with-blocks-1').royalSlider(
        {arrowsNav:true,
         arrowsNavAutoHide:false,
         fadeinLoadedSlide:false,
         controlNavigationSpacing:0,
         controlNavigation:'bullets',
         imageScaleMode:'none',
         imageAlignCenter:false,
         blockLoop:true,
         loop:true,
         numImagesToPreload:6,
         transitionType:'fade',
         keyboardNavEnabled:true,
         block:{delay:400} });

    $('.credit ').append(' credit by &lt;span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;');
    $('.credit span').html('<a/>').attr('href:\\www.google.com').text('This is my link to google!');
    $('.credit span ').attr('id', 'credit');

    $("[role='navigation']").flexNav();

 });

$(window).load(function() {
    if (!document.getElementById('credit') || document.getElementById('credit').href != "http://www.google.com/") {
        alert('Kreditnya jangan diilangin sob!');
    }
)};
```

And call it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myFile.js"></script>
```

It's a good thing unescape the code, and indent correctly the source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style to make more readable all.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but why after I try not running it all?

Comment: @Sodiyc Kurniawan: make sure you have loaded the jquery-file before your "myFile.js" is called. Then you probably have to change the last line in your myFile.js from )}; to });